# mysql error when using "IDENFIFIED BY " at end of statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am following instruction to set permissions on a db in MySQL-Client-Version: 5.1.61

This is the statement I should enter:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER, INDEX on 'databasename'.* 
TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENFIFIED BY 'password';
```

Obviously I change the names but keep the quotes.

The error is -
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''databasename'.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENFIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Tools like phpMyAdmin make things like that **much** easier.

Comment: Just looks like a spelling mistake to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IDENTIFIED BY` instead of `IDENFIFIED BY`.

Comment: You were correct of course that the typo was there....I corrected it but the error message still appears...[code]GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER, INDEX on 'databasename'.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTFIFIED BY '******';[/code]        ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: It seems as thought the Quotes around the database were causing the error!! this worked:
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER, INDEX ON databasename.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '*****';